# do i really need to implement a refresh token rotation for next auth when using credentials provider?

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, authorization, next-auth

I was watching some videos on YouTube about implementing credential-based authentication using next-auth, and in some of them, I saw people putting user data, access tokens, and refresh tokens inside the session. Then I wondered if this really makes sense because, in my mind, wouldn't the session cookie generated by next-auth be sufficient for user verification?

I really enjoy implementing my own JWT authentication system with access tokens and refresh tokens, but whenever I create it and try to implement the Axios interceptor on the front end, the flow doesn't feel quite smooth, so to speak. That's why I decided to opt for a ready-made authentication service like next-auth. I'm open to suggestions for better ways to implement authentication :)